# MDX - Exclude columns with (null) or zero values

Tags: ssms, mdx, cube, olap-cube, ssms-2014

I'm working on a cube query in SSMS 2014, and my query is returning all columns, even those that include 0's and (null) values. I understand this is because the Date and Client Name are not empty.

With my MDX query below, how can I remove any column that includes a (null) value, or a count of zero for logins?

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [2MonthsPriorUniqueUsers] AS Sum({[Date].[Calendar Year Month].CurrentMember.Lag(2)},[Measures].[App Unique Users Loggedin]) 
  MEMBER [1MonthPriorUniqueUsers] AS Sum({[Date].[Calendar Year Month].CurrentMember.Lag(1)},[Measures].[App Unique Users Loggedin]) 
  MEMBER [1MonthPriorTotalAppLogins] AS Sum({[Date].[Calendar Year Month].CurrentMember.Lag(1)},[Measures].[App Logins])
  MEMBER [Measures].[PercentUniqueIncreaseMoM] AS ([1MonthPriorUniqueUsers] / [2MonthsPriorUniqueUsers])-1,FORMAT_STRING = "Percent" 
SELECT 
   NON EMPTY 
     {[Date].[Calendar Year Month].[201705]}
   *  [Project].[Client Name].members ON 0,
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[PercentUniqueIncreaseMoM]
     ,([1MonthPriorUniqueUsers])
     ,[2MonthsPriorUniqueUsers]
     ,[1MonthPriorTotalAppLogins]
    } ON 1
FROM [MyCube]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [NonEmpty()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/nonempty-mdx) or the [Filter()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/filter-mdx) functions. For example, if you need to exclude empty records based on [Measures].[App Logins]:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [2MonthsPriorUniqueUsers] AS Sum({[Date].[Calendar Year Month].CurrentMember.Lag(2)},[Measures].[App Unique Users Loggedin]) 
  MEMBER [1MonthPriorUniqueUsers] AS Sum({[Date].[Calendar Year Month].CurrentMember.Lag(1)},[Measures].[App Unique Users Loggedin]) 
  MEMBER [1MonthPriorTotalAppLogins] AS Sum({[Date].[Calendar Year Month].CurrentMember.Lag(1)},[Measures].[App Logins])
  MEMBER [Measures].[PercentUniqueIncreaseMoM] AS ([1MonthPriorUniqueUsers] / [2MonthsPriorUniqueUsers])-1,FORMAT_STRING = "Percent" 
SELECT 
   NON EMPTY 
     {[Date].[Calendar Year Month].[201705]}
   *  Filter([Project].[Client Name].members,[Measures].[App Logins]>0) ON 0,
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[PercentUniqueIncreaseMoM]
     ,([1MonthPriorUniqueUsers])
     ,[2MonthsPriorUniqueUsers]
     ,[1MonthPriorTotalAppLogins]
    } ON 1
FROM [MyCube]
```

Comment: That did the trick for the (null) values and I greatly appreciate that, but what about any values that are zero?

Comment: See the updated answer. The easiest way is the Filter() function.

Comment: I'm still getting zero values @Danylo... While doing some testing (increasing the number I am filtering by), I noticed that even when the number is increased significantly, say to >300, I get results where there are significantly less than 300 [Measures].[App Logins] (for instance, 25 App Logins). Any further suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you are using [Measures].[App Logins] to check the value?

Comment: I am sure.  Do you think that for some reason it is counting the App Logins for all time, and not just for that date period?

Comment: I don't know, try Filter([Project].[Client Name].Members,[Measures].[App Logins]>0).Count and [Project].[Client Name].Members.Count. Whether they return the same value.